# Error install requirements.txt Django project Mac M1

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I got my Django project via gitlab and put it on my Macbook M1 but when I put myself in the virtual environment and I install the requirements I have a long error message that appears, I don't don't know how to fix this.

Could it be because of the apple silicon chip?

Here is the error message:

```
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/pierro/Documents/permacool/api_permacool/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/f2/r4cvtlb53hb3r3bvpzkmqnyr0000gn/T/pip-install-zdiid0g3/mysqlclient_87a039d3b25c4c3f8c32778ba1e13516/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/f2/r4cvtlb53hb3r3bvpzkmqnyr0000gn/T/pip-install-zdiid0g3/mysqlclient_87a039d3b25c4c3f8c32778ba1e13516/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/f2/r4cvtlb53hb3r3bvpzkmqnyr0000gn/T/pip-record-bh773nfm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/pierro/Documents/permacool/api_permacool/include/site/python3.8/mysqlclient
     cwd: /private/var/folders/f2/r4cvtlb53hb3r3bvpzkmqnyr0000gn/T/pip-install-zdiid0g3/mysqlclient_87a039d3b25c4c3f8c32778ba1e13516/
Complete output (43 lines):
mysql_config --version
['8.0.28']
mysql_config --libs
['-L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib', '-lmysqlclient', '-lz', '-lzstd', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-lresolv']
mysql_config --cflags
['-I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/include/mysql']
ext_options:
  library_dirs: ['/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib']
  libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'zstd', 'resolv']
  extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
  extra_link_args: []
  include_dirs: ['/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/include/mysql']
  extra_objects: []
  define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,0,3,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.0.3')]
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/include/mysql -I/Users/pierro/Documents/permacool/api_permacool/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-headerpad,0x1000 build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/lib -lmysqlclient -lzstd -lresolv -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lzstd
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you installed `mysql-client`? Via brew, for example?

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876857/mysqlclient-wont-install-via-pip-on-macbook-pro-m1-with-latest-version-of-big-s/70625991

Comment: yes I installed `mysql-client` but still the same error

Comment: Thanks for the link I'll look but I think I've done a lot of the things proposed but still the same...

Answer (score 0):

It is all good.  I just changed the version of mysql-client in the requirements.txt because the version I downloaded with Brew was older